# 3D plot: smooth plot on x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, z-axis

I have a 3D polygon plot and want to smooth the plot on the y axis (i.e. I want it to look like 'slices of a surface plot').

Consider this MWE (taken from [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xs = np.arange(-10, 10, 2)
verts = []
zs = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

for z in zs:
    ys = np.random.rand(len(xs))
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[mcolors.to_rgba('r', alpha=0.6),
                                         mcolors.to_rgba('g', alpha=0.6), 
                                         mcolors.to_rgba('b', alpha=0.6), 
                                         mcolors.to_rgba('y', alpha=0.6)])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 4)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

Now, I want to replace the four plots with normal distributions (to ideally form continuous lines).

I have created the distributions here:

```
def get_xs(lwr_bound = -4, upr_bound = 4, n = 80):
    """ generates the x space betwee lwr_bound and upr_bound so that it has n intermediary steps """
    xs = np.arange(lwr_bound, upr_bound, (upr_bound - lwr_bound) / n) # x space -- number of points on l/r dimension
    return(xs)

xs = get_xs()

dists = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def get_distribution_params(list_):
    """ generates the distribution parameters (mu and sigma) for len(list_) distributions"""
    mus = []
    sigmas = []
    for i in range(len(dists)):
        mus.append(round((i + 1) + 0.1 * np.random.randint(0,10), 3))
        sigmas.append(round((i + 1) * .01 * np.random.randint(0,10), 3))
    return mus, sigmas

mus, sigmas = get_distribution_params(dists)

def get_distributions(list_, xs, mus, sigmas):
    """ generates len(list_) normal distributions, with different mu and sigma values """
    distributions = [] # distributions

    for i in range(len(list_)):
        x_ = xs
        z_ = norm.pdf(xs, loc = mus[i], scale = sigmas[0])
        distributions.append(list(zip(x_, z_)))
        #print(x_[60], z_[60])

    return distributions

distributions = get_distributions(list_ = dists, xs = xs, mus = mus, sigmas = sigmas)
```

But adding them to the code (with `poly = PolyCollection(distributions, ...)` and `ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=distributions, zdir='z')` throws a `ValueError` (`ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping`) I cannot resolve.

Comment: Please add your complete non-working example with imports, norm is missing and topics = dists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by passing `distributions` to `zs` where `zs` expects that when `verts` in `PolyCollection` has shape *MxNx2* the object passed to `zs` has shape *M*. So when it reaches this check

```py
cpdef ndarray broadcast_to(ndarray array, shape):
    # ...
    if array.ndim < len(shape):
        raise ValueError(
            'input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis '
            'remapping')
    # ...
```

in the underlying numpy code, it fails. I believe this occurs because the number of dimensions expected (`array.ndim`) is less than the number of dimensions of `zs` (`len(shape)`). It is expecting an array of shape `(4,)` but receives an array of shape `(4, 80, 2)`.

This error can be resolved by using an array of the correct shape - e.g. `zs` from the original example or `dists` from your code. Using `zs=dists` and adjusting the axis limits to `[0,5]` for `x`, `y`, and `z` gives

[image]

This looks a bit odd for two reasons:

1. There is a typo in `z_ = norm.pdf(xs, loc = mus[i], scale = sigmas[0])` which gives all the distributions the same sigma, it should be `z_ = norm.pdf(xs, loc = mus[i], scale = sigmas[i])`
2. The viewing geometry: the distributions have the positive `xz` plane as their base, this is also the plane we are looking through.

Changing the viewing geometry via [`ax.view_init`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init) will yield a clearer plot:

[image]

---

### Edit

Here is the complete code which generates the plot shown,

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

np.random.seed(8)
def get_xs(lwr_bound = -4, upr_bound = 4, n = 80):
    return np.arange(lwr_bound, upr_bound, (upr_bound - lwr_bound) / n)

def get_distribution_params(list_):
    mus = [round((i+1) + 0.1 * np.random.randint(0,10), 3) for i in range(len(dists))]
    sigmas = [round((i+1) * .01 * np.random.randint(0,10), 3) for i in range(len(dists))]
    return mus, sigmas

def get_distributions(list_, xs, mus, sigmas):
    return [list(zip(xs, norm.pdf(xs, loc=mus[i], scale=sigmas[i] if sigmas[i] != 0.0 
            else 0.1))) for i in range(len(list_))]

dists = [1, 2, 3, 4]
xs = get_xs()
mus, sigmas = get_distribution_params(dists)
distributions = get_distributions(dists, xs, mus, sigmas)

fc = [mcolors.to_rgba('r', alpha=0.6), mcolors.to_rgba('g', alpha=0.6), 
      mcolors.to_rgba('b', alpha=0.6), mcolors.to_rgba('y', alpha=0.6)]

poly = PolyCollection(distributions, fc=fc)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=np.array(dists).astype(float), zdir='z')
ax.view_init(azim=115)
ax.set_zlim([0, 5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
```

I based it off the code you provide in the question, but made some modifications for brevity and to be more consistent with the usual styling.

---

**Note**   -   The example code you have given will fail depending on the `np.random.seed()`, in order to ensure it works I have added a check in the call to `norm.pdf` which ensures the scale is non-zero: `scale = sigma[i] if sigma[i] != 0.0 else 0.1`.

Comment: Hi William, Thanks a lot for your response! I couldn't quite reproduce your code (i.e. understand which snippets to include where) without further errors making me think I got it wrong. Could you clarify how the code you're suggesting looks? :) Many thanks!

Comment: @Ivo I would be happy to, but it may take me a couple days to get around to it.... feel free to ping me if I haven’t updated my answer in a few days

Comment: have you found the time yet to look at this? :)

Comment: @Ivo I haven't quite yet - I got kinda busy, but I plan to soon. Thanks for pinging me

Comment: @Ivo I've added the complete code I use to generate the plot shown - hopefully that will help clarify things

Answer (score 1):

Using `ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=dists, zdir='z')` instead of `ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=distributions, zdir='z')` should fix the issue.

---

Additionally, you might want to replace

```py
def get_xs(lwr_bound = -4, upr_bound = 4, n = 80):
    """ generates the x space betwee lwr_bound and upr_bound so that it has n intermediary steps """
    xs = np.arange(lwr_bound, upr_bound, (upr_bound - lwr_bound) / n) # x space -- number of points on l/r dimension
    return(xs)

xs = get_xs()
```

by

```py
xs = np.linspace(-4, 4, 80)
```

---

Also, I believe the `scale = sigmas[0]` should actually be `scale = sigmas[i]` in the line

```py
z_ = norm.pdf(xs, loc = mus[i], scale = sigmas[0])
```

---

Finally, I believe you should adjust the `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim` appropriatly, as you swapped the `y` and `z` dimensions of the plot and changed its scales when comparing to the reference code.